# PCT change formula

Tags: python, pandas

New to python, I have been doing some practice and I dont understand how this line of code works and why does it work.

It takes every value in a cell/row and divides it with the starting value, why?

Help much appreciated :)

PS This is exactly what I need, I just dont understand the process behind it (Im aware of the `.pct_change()`)

```
df['num2'] = (df['num2'] - df['num2'][0]) / df['num2'][0] * 100.0
```

Here is the entire code

```
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods = 7)
df = pd.DataFrame(dates)

nums = {'num2' : [1,2,4,8,16,32,64]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(nums)

df = df.join(df2, how = 'left')

df.rename(columns = {0 : 'Dates'}, inplace = True)
df = df.set_index('Dates')

#df = df.pct_change()
df['num2'] = (df['num2'] - df['num2'][0]) / df['num2'][0] * 100.0

df.plot()

print (df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These values are the occurences of a time-dependent variable. It appears that your code compute growth rates. As follows

```
growth_rate = (what_it_is - what_it_was)/what_it_was
```

Something which is not really "clean" is that it changes orginal `dict` contained values by these growth rates, meaning that there is a loss of information by doing so.

To give you an idea, what is done is (even if **what follows is not python-syntaxically correct**)

```
([1,2,4,8,16,32,64] - 1)/1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['num2'] = df['num2'][1:]/df['num2'][:-1].values-1
```